# series pass power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

High output voltages are common during failure (i.e., shorting) of the series-pass element, in a switching power supply. Failure of the switching element generally results  in a condition of?

Comment: results in a condition of failing the class because you're asking the exact question on stack overflow verbatim

Comment: .... failure I believe, the condition is called failure

Comment: Sadness? Panic? "Letting the smoke out"?

Comment: How ironic that it should "pass" when it "fails"

Answer (score 2):

> Failure of the switching element generally results in a condition of?

[image: Explosion!]

Comment: Humorous, but vague.  Lots of things could happen when the switch "fails", from no output to loss of regulation, to the above.